# I was trying to solve a complex number to a power using de Moivre's Identity but got stuck.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

One of the assignments that I have to solve is:

$(7-i)^3$

I know that I can simply open the exponent since it is only 3 but I tried to use de Moivre's Identity.

$\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{7})$

$r=\sqrt{7^{2}+(-1)^{2}}=\sqrt{50}$

$z^{n}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=50^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos(3\cdot\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{7}))+i\sin(3\cdot\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{7})))$

How can I find out what the cosine of an arc-tangent is?

Comment: You draw a representative triangle. If the sides are $7$ and $-1$, then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{50}$, and the cosine is adjacent/hypotenuse.

Comment: (Let's not forget that an arctan is *an angle*. We know how to find the cosine of an angle - in a right triangle, of course - from SOHCAHTOA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$, so $\arctan\left(\dfrac{-1}{7}\right)=-\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)$ and we also can simplify $\sqrt{50}=\sqrt{2\times25}=5\sqrt{2}$. Then your last expression simplifies to $$(7-i)^3=5\sqrt{2}\cos\left(3\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)-5\sqrt{2}i\sin\left(3\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)$$

Now, to really answer your question, first we need to get rid of that $3$ factor using the following trigonometric identities: $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^3,$$$$\cos(3x)=\cos(x)^3-3\cos(x)\sin(x)^2;$$ these can easily be derived for arbitrary integer factor once you learn about complex exponentiation and generally for arbitrary (symbolic) factor using the binomial theorem.

We have $$(7-i)^3=5\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)^3-3\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)^2\right)-5\sqrt{2}i\left(3\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)^2-\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)^3\right);\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
now we can evaluate $\sin\circ\arctan$ and $\cos\circ\arctan$: just recall
$$\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1;$$
we want to have $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of $\tan$ to cancel $\arctan$, therefore divide by $\sin(x)^2$:
$$1+1/\tan(x)^2=1/\sin(x)^2\implies$$
$$\implies \sin(x)^2=\frac{1}{1+1/\tan(x)^2}=\frac{\tan(x)^2}{\tan(x)^2+1}$$
$$\implies \sin(x)=\pm\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt{\tan(x)^2+1}},$$
$$\sin(\arctan(\alpha))=\frac{\tan(\arctan(\alpha))}{\sqrt{\tan(\arctan(\alpha))^2+1}}=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}};$$
and $\cos(x)^2$:
$$\tan(x)^2+1=1/\cos(x)^2\implies$$
$$\implies\cos(x)^2=\frac{1}{\tan(x)^2+1}$$
$$\implies\cos(x)=\pm\frac{1}{\tan(x)^2+1},$$
$$\cos(\arctan(\alpha))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan(\arctan(\alpha))^2+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}};$$
in particular then, we have
$$\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)=\frac{1/7}{\sqrt{1/7^2+1}}=\frac{1}{7\sqrt{1/7^2+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7^2+1}}=50^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{5}2^{-1/2},$$
$$\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/7^2+1}}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{7^2+1}}=\frac{7}{5}2^{-1/2};$$
substituting that in $\eqref{eq1}$ will yield the desired form after a bit of simplification.

Comment: Thank you for that helpful comment. I can see that me teacher wanted me to simply open the equation and not use de Moivre's Identity but it is nice to know that de Moivre's Identity is one that can be used on all complex numbers and not just nice ones that the teacher gave me.

You mentioned the 3factor identity. If the number was 5*θ or something greater would you have been able to solve it?

Comment: @elsa, sure. Well, in fact those multiple-angle trigonometric identities come directly from the de Moivre's formula; for example, for double angle we have: $$\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^2=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2+i2\sin(x)\cos(x); $$ now notice for the LHS to be equal to the RHS we need their real and imaginary parts to be equal: $$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2,$$ $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x);$$ so using the de Moivre's formula plus trigonometric identities isn't really a shortcut: the formula and binomial expansion is actually the fastest way to derive the trigonometric formulae themselves.

Comment: Thanks, you have given me a bigger incite into how these formulas were made and work.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
$\cos A=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 A}}$ or $\sin A=\dfrac{\tan A}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 A}}$